# Firebase function to get 10 items at each request sending parameters via url

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Currently I am working on a project where i want get data from firebase to an ESP32, I want to process 10 JSON objects at a time because RAM limitations. I have the following javascript function to ask for the data:

```
exports.getData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const path = request.query.path;
  const limit = parseInt(request.query.limit, 10) || 10; 
  const startAtValue = request.query.startAt; 

  if (!path) {
    return response.status(400).send("Path query parameter is required");
  }

  const ref = admin.database().ref(path);

  let query = ref;
  if (startAtValue) {
    query = query.startAt(startAtValue);
  }
  query = query.limitToFirst(limit);

  query
    .once("value", (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      response.send(data);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

It works when i do a first request:
`https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/getData?path=/path/to/data&limit=11`

I get data like this

```
{
  "77303837": "77303837,12,-16,0",
  "77303868": "77303868,12,-16,0",
  "77303929": "77303929,12,-16,0",
  "77304889": "77304889,14,-16,0",
  "77304971": "77304971,12,-16,0",
  "77305435": "77305435,14,-16,0",
  "4072700001089": "4072700001089,0,0,0",
  "4792128005888": "4792128005888,0,0,0",
  "5410228202929": "5410228202929,2,0,0",
  "5410228217732": "5410228217732,0,0,0",
  "5410228243564": "5410228243564,1,0,0"
}
```

but it fails when i do a sencond one like:
`https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/getData?path=/path/to/data&limit=10&startAt=5410228243564`

Any help is appreciated

I not a JavaScript expert but accordingly to the Firebase documentation this should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What's happening that's different than what you expect? Is there an error message?  Please edit the question to share what you observe.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/1999fmv/firebase_function_to_get_10_items_at_each_request/

Answer (score 0):

A query in the Firebase Realtime Database consists of:

1. An instruction to **order** the direct child nodes of the path your querying on a value at a fixed path under each node. This can be done with methods: `orderByChild`, `orderByKey` and `orderByValue`.
2. An instruction to then **filter** the nodes based on those values. This is done with methods like `startAt`, `endAt`, `equalTo`, etc
3. An instruction to limit the resulting node count with `limitToFirst` or `limitToLast`.

Your code is missing the an `orderBy` instruction, which is probably why it doesn't work. Since it seems you want to order by the value of each node under the path, call `orderByValue`:

```
let query = ref.orderByValue();
```